# Просмотр ключей. Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, key

Есть проблема. 
Не могу дропнуть таблицу, так как говорит о том что есть ключи, связанные с ней

> ORA-02449: unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys

Также не могу добавить в нее строку так как вылазит ошибка об отсутствии родительского ключа.

> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.ARTISTFK) violated - parent key not
>   found

Comment: Найдите какие таблицы ссылаются на удаляемую и удалите их или их ограничения внешнего ключа (foreign key). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143728/how-can-i-find-which-tables-reference-a-given-table-in-oracle-sql-developer

Answer (score 5):

Oшибка `ORA-02449: unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys` обычно возникает, когда между двумя таблицами установлены внешние отношения. Затем вы попытались удалить родительскую таблицу, не удаляя внешний ключ.

Чтобы исправить эту проблему, вам нужно сначала удалить внешний ключ, а затем вы можете удалить родительскую таблицу.

Например:

```
CREATE TABLE supplier
( 
  supplier_id   numeric(10)  not null,
  supplier_name varchar2(50) not null,
  contact_name  varchar2(50),
  CONSTRAINT supplier_pk PRIMARY KEY (supplier_id)
);

CREATE TABLE products
( 
  product_id  numeric(10) not null,
  supplier_id numeric(10) not null,
  CONSTRAINT fk_supplier
    FOREIGN KEY (supplier_id)
    REFERENCES supplier (supplier_id)
);
```

Затем вы попытались удалить родительскую таблицу следующим образом:

```
DROP TABLE supplier;
```

Вы получите следующее сообщение об ошибке:
`ORA-02449: unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys`.

Поскольку внешний ключ с именем `fk_supplier` существует, сначала необходимо удалить это ограничение следующим образом:

```
ALTER TABLE products
  DROP CONSTRAINT fk_supplier;
```

Затем вы можете удалить родительскую таблицу:

```
DROP TABLE supplier;
```

Oшибка `ORA-02291: integrity constraint <constraint name> violated - parent key not found` обычно возникает, когда между двумя таблицами установлены внешние отношения. Затем вы попытались вставить значение в дочернюю таблицу, но соответствующее значение не существует в родительской таблице.

Чтобы исправить эту проблему, сначала нужно вставить значение в родительскую таблицу, а затем вставить соответствующее значение в дочернюю таблицу.

Воспользуемся существующими таблицами для примера.
Затем попробуйте вставить в таблицу продуктов следующее:

```
INSERT INTO products(product_id, supplier_id) VALUES (1001, 5000);
```

Вы получите следующее сообщение об ошибке: `ORA-02291: integrity constraint <constraint name> violated - parent key not found`

Поскольку значение supplier_id, равное 5000, еще не существует в таблице поставщиков, необходимо сначала вставить запись в таблицу поставщиков следующим образом:

```
INSERT INTO supplier(supplier_id, supplier_name, contact_name)
  VALUES (5000, 'Microsoft', 'Bill Gates');
```

Затем вы можете вставить в таблицу продуктов:

```
INSERT INTO products(product_id, supplier_id) VALUES (1001, 5000);
```

Чтоб посмотреть список первичных и внешних ключей в таблицы можно через следующие запросы:

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER_CONS_COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'имя_таблицы'
    AND CONSTRAINT_NAME IN (SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME
        FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
        WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN('P', 'R'));
```

а если же есть стандартное обозначение первичных ключей и внешних ключей в системе, то:

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER_CONS_COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'имя_таблицы'
    AND (CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE 'PK%' 
    OR CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE 'FK%');
```